# Unable to select dropdown value using ng-model First item is getting selected as blank

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to select my dropdown value inside a AngularJS function by setting the value to the ng-model . But when i look up in the HTML the drop down is coming in with blank value selected first . This is my HTML

```
<select class="pulldown" ng-model="test" ng-options="obj as obj.desc for identifier track by obj.value" ></select>
        <td><span style="padding-left:1px"></td></td></td>
```

This is my Angular JS function inside the controller

```
$scope.modify = function(details){
$scope.identifier = [{"value" : "0","desc":"single"},{"value":"ABC","desc":""multiple"}]
$scope.test = details.employee ;
// Here details.employee can be ABC or 1 .Depending upon this ABC/1 I am trying to populate my HTML as Single / Multiple 
}
```

This is loading me with blank value selected as first . I want the value Single / multiple to be populated depending upon the value in details.employee where am i going wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct your [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) syntax :

```
<select ng-options='obj.value as obj.desc for obj in identifier' ng-model='test'></select>
```

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    
    $scope.identifier = [
    {value : "0",desc:"single"},
    {value:"ABC",desc:"multiple"}
    ];
    
    $scope.test = $scope.identifier[0].value;
    
    $scope.getVal = function(test) {
      console.log(test);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model='test' ng-options='obj.value as obj.desc for obj in identifier' ng-change="getVal(test)"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to set the `$scope.test` dynamically .It can contain value as  0 or ABC .Going by your answer it would fail for ABC

Comment: Check my updated answer it is working fine for ABC also.

Answer (score 0):

You defined wrong `ng-options`:

```
ng-options="obj as obj.desc for identifier track by obj.value"
```

So Change your:

```
<select class="pulldown" ng-model="test" ng-options="obj as obj.desc for identifier track by obj.value" ></select>
```

to

```
<select class="pulldown" name="test" ng-model="test" ng-options="obj.value as obj.desc for obj in identifier" >
```

And now it will work as you expected. See jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/oaaf04fk/)

Comment: What error you are getting? It's working for me here.

Comment: angular.min.js:101 Error: [ngOptions:iexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/ngOptions/iexp?p0=obj%20as"<select class="pulldown ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="test" ng-options="obj as obj.desc for identifier track by obj.value">"bj.desc%for%identifier%20track%20by%obj.value&p1=%3Cselect%class%3D%22pulldown%20ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%20ng-model%3D%22test%22%20ng-options%3D%obj%20as%obj.desc%for%identifier%20track%20by%obj.value%22%3E . This is the error

Comment: see this: https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/oaaf04fk/ I updated in answer also.

Comment: I found the issue , It is working because you have declared the `test` as `$scope.test = '0' ;` . In my case the value in the `details.employee` is coming as `0` it is coming without `single quotes` . It is failing because of that . how can i fix this

Comment: Try: `num.toString();`